# JSON.stringify (Javascript) and json.dumps (Python) not equivalent on a list?

Tags: javascript, python, json

In javascript:

```
var myarray = [2, 3];
var json_myarray = JSON.stringify(myarray) // '[2,3]'
```

But in Python:

```
import json 
mylist = [2, 3]
json_mylist = json.dumps(mylist) # '[2, 3]' <-- Note the space
```

So the 2 functions aren't equivalent. It's a bit unexpected for me and a bit problematic when trying to compare some data for example.

Some explanation about it?

Comment: If you're comparing serialized JSON values exactly, what will you do about the ordering of object keys?

Comment: JSON allows for whitespace between elements; the Python default configuration is to include that whitespace. What is your actual goal here, to compare the JSON *value* or the exact bytes that are generated by etiher? If the latter, you'll have more issues, like the order of key-value pairs in JSON objects not being set.

Comment: The outputs are equivalent, just not the same. JSON has some flexibility when it comes to encoding the same data, it doesn't mandate a canonical form. Whitespace is one example, the use of \u escaping in strings is another.

Comment: Granted, I can convert the json string to object like a list and doing the comparison. but I found it more direct to compare directly that. The JSON string is in a database, representing a field for a ForeignKey (Django framework) that I'm searching. (And the ordering is important).

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The difference is that `json.dumps` applies some minor pretty-printing by default but `JSON.stringify` does not.

To remove all whitespace, like `JSON.stringify`, you need to [specify the separators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

```
json_mylist = json.dumps(mylist, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Comment: It may work for simple arrays only. Arrays with objects inside still produce different checksums, so they differ (they have extra chars).

Comment: To make it indent one can use the indent = indent_size parameter