# 3DES crypto on Python produces different result from Nodejs/Java

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, cryptography, 3des

Im bulding a checkout that need creditcard 3DES Crypto,
but I getting differente result on Python and NodeJs.

Python code:
(im using pycryptodome package)

```
import binascii
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
import json

iv = '04njBuE3/dc='
iv = base64.b64decode(iv)
key = 'DpzDLcvVCHdVoRqE/NuIHs0QJ0xFdH2p'
key = base64.b64decode(key)
data = {'CartaoNumero': '0000000000000000',
'CartaoMesAno':'00/0000',
'CartaoSeg': '000',
'CartaoNome':'Teste Teste',
'IdentFatura':'Teste',
'Valor':'1000',
'NomeCliente':'Teste Teste',
'EmailCliente':'teste@teste.com',
'CpfCliente':'11122233344'}
data = json.dumps(data)
data = base64.b64encode(data.encode('utf-8'))
#print (data)

def card_encrypt(iv,key, data):
    desT = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
    desT_key = desT.encrypt(data)
    desT_key = base64.b64encode(desT_key)
    return (desT_key)
```

> Result:
> b'+TSfdiGmLAir8RVEze4yr72d3Sm5RBkDBwLYhpv1NKIIfVM+AnIhoSArFzV5am7qOdaFO0Ob4KSS8vXRYnBAO1xyk9MEoNc93uf/53cCMVHbZ8FUx14Vilx3Mg8+kbSMsASki5Dn+hlKE0ElFC/nyiWoOJvkWmtndoL+EEb4rkFil0zg637YXFE7f0yTOWhz97G6CEb4mvegCPpizuVdh2sBQQFDsJMEQE1kGeY2gDiDADwRQiMTrznhWFn3H6SylMxjQaNJTxu820BNitefMgcwAUTUJSrZt6DyuJ59e7772DK2jLubpK8/8xNolKalcjYMx106T7jOxDoPWZEoIe7YSGn9+Z3IGe5R7YFQJVLJUJ3SzlwWLptr3ZbMRnDCh2rB4FbTsM4igic4ZUQjS3DUzUVpT5URQyGjJK9+434ivMehknko4x+1owaEgcLGsPT9zBADlKFQ+OE8JqOhwJ5IztyoWeOmBVPZsOQdYvo='

Nodejs code:

```
var secretKey = 'DpzDLcvVCHdVoRqE/NuIHs0QJ0xFdH2p'
 var secretIV = '04njBuE3/dc='
 var dataOfCard = {'CartaoNumero': '0000000000000000',
'CartaoMesAno':'00/0000',
'CartaoSeg': '000',
'CartaoNome':'Teste Teste',
'IdentFatura':'Teste',
'Valor':'1000',
'NomeCliente':'Teste Teste',
'EmailCliente':'teste@teste.com',
'CpfCliente':'11122233344'}

const crypto = require('crypto');
 
async function encryptCardData(dataOfCard, secretKey, secretIV) {
    try {
        const des3_key = new Buffer.from(secretKey, "base64");
        console.log(des3_key)
        const des3_iv = new Buffer.from(secretIV, "base64");
        console.log(des3_iv)
        const cardString = JSON.stringify(dataOfCard);
        console.log(cardString)
      
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', des3_key, des3_iv);

        const encrypted = cipher.update(cardString, 'utf8', 'base64');
    
        return encrypted + cipher.final('base64');        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

encryptCardData(dataOfCard, secretKey, secretIV)
```

> Result:
> '7pkXCZCKIDY1ueGwkfLk5W5AnDw2iP4jiZ5YHUBRMd56eDhVyZvnJ6EG+mh/wmHl3ljrJ+sfDMgAbpOgljRRQb4pOc1LQKHdkgcl3ZWmlvmqv8mGKdGaZYTgXnQ9pZGwoUQJAcuQgOCYWD5wMvIA6g4zd8O1iy/IsXWkBEzCkQA3x6NIkwrCNdftogu3JZlbmOIj90flo8t+J2X89rXzQmWKw6uCWrzzfGQvmvqqNf7ecDduTtCXee3WCdvcC3Ar7TbVpSv+NenoK+Oh+Tkj6Y8h4t6YAexyE8HxQ1GqCqFlMAzdCa2TtA=='

The NodeJS is generating the correct result.
What I need to correct on Python model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python code differs from the NodeJS code for the following reasons:

- The conversion to a JSON string with `json.dumps()` is slightly different from that with `JSON.stringify()`. `json.dumps()`, unlike `JSON.stringify()`, inserts spaces after the separators (for better readability), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227888/9014097). To avoid this, use the following modification:

  ```
  dataJSON = json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))
  ```
- In the NodeJS code, padding is done *implicitly* with PKCS7, but not in Python. Here the padding must be performed *explicitly*, for which PyCryptodome provides a [padding module](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module):

  ```
  from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
  ...
  dataPadded = pad(dataJSON.encode('utf-8'), 8)
  ```

  8 is the 3DES block size in bytes.
- The Base64 encoding of the data must be removed:

  ```
  #data = base64.b64encode(data.encode('utf-8'))
  ```

With that:

```
ciphertext = card_encrypt(iv,key, dataPadded)
print (ciphertext)
```

returns the ciphertext:

```
b'7pkXCZCKIDY1ueGwkfLk5W5AnDw2iP4jiZ5YHUBRMd56eDhVyZvnJ6EG+mh/wmHl3ljrJ+sfDMgAbpOgljRRQb4pOc1LQKHdkgcl3ZWmlvmqv8mGKdGaZYTgXnQ9pZGwoUQJAcuQgOCYWD5wMvIA6g4zd8O1iy/IsXWkBEzCkQA3x6NIkwrCNdftogu3JZlbmOIj90flo8t+J2X89rXzQmWKw6uCWrzzfGQvmvqqNf7ecDduTtCXee3WCdvcC3Ar7TbVpSv+NenoK+Oh+Tkj6Y8h4t6YAexyE8HxQ1GqCqFlMAzdCa2TtA=='
```

which matches the ciphertext of the NodeJS code.

Please note that 3DES is deprecated and should be replaced by e.g. the more modern and performant AES, s. [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181). Apart from that, the use of a static IV is generally insecure, s [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10511).

Comment: Excellent!
It worked very well!! Thank youo for this help!!